# Why are there cells treated different from "0" in google sheets, even though they're blank?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I know that Google Sheets treats blank cells as if they're a 0 number (You can multiply a number by a blank cell and there's no error).

I would like to have some insight on why a supposedly blank cell is not treated as 0 (if I delete it, cell becomes blank as normal).

I'll share a sheet to show what I mean. Thanks for the help
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cXhQcwUYhCNMUc06o5x48QeJtjXwQSPRBycydQ639_M

Here the cell C2 isn't blank and it's not treated as 0, but I cannot understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blank and null are not the same thing. For instance, a cell that never held a value is blank and equal to zero, while a cell that had a null string (i.e., "") copied into it is null text.

This can happen, for instance, with an IF formula such as this:

`=IF(LEN(A2:A),A2:A+1,"")`

This is different from the following:

`=IF(LEN(A2:A),A2:A+1,)`

The first formula pastes a null string into each cell were A2:A has no length; the second formula does nothing (i.e., leaves it truly blank).

If you hardcopy the results of the first formula to another location, you will copy over the null text string as well.

You can test what's in a cell that *appears* empty with `=ISBLANK( )` and `ISTEXT( )`.